# cannot type in vi when trying to edit the interfaces file

Tags: server, vi

I am trying to edit the interfaces file so I can put in my network settings.

This is what I'm typing:

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

The file pulls up fine. I seem to be able to delete all rows, inadvertently, by hitting the  D key... which really confuses me.

It won't let me type, at all.

I cannot use any other editor since I cannot connect to the internet until I get this file updated.

I only have 1 user on the system and I'm logged in as that. At least, during the install, that is all they prompted me for.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: that worked, any idea why it wouldn't let me in vi?

Comment: Maybe because you were expecting Vim but you got the "rustic" Vi interface (which can get confusing after getting cozy with Vim non-compatible).

Comment: if you want to post that as an answer I will upvote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are expecting the coziness of Vim's non-compatible mode, try using `nano` instead:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

After getting your Internet connection, you can install `vim` if you feel more comfy with it.